# Ubuntu Server 14.04 and 12.04 installation problem

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I have used Ubuntu Server 12.04 from an USB-Drive on my NAS for some time but it got damaged so I bought an SSD-drive to replace it. I waited for the Ubuntu 14.04 release and installed that, installation went through but it won't start, it loads for some time and then get stuck at:
EXT4-fs (sdg1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null).

I then made a new USB with Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 to install that again, but when I choose "Install Ubuntu Server" from the GRUB-menu the system just reboots. Same thing if I choose "check disc". I then thought the USB-Drive maybe was faulty. So I got a new one and tried with that, same thing.

The system I have is ASUS E45M1-I DELUXE AMD FUSION E-450 MINI-ITX.

What can I do to make a successful install of Ubuntu?

Comment: dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/456530/ubuntu-server-14-04-and-12-04-installation-problem

Comment: @bain question cannot be a duplicate of itself.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this issue and was VERY frustrated by it.  I noticed it happening when I ran 14.04 (only OS installed on 500GB HDD) on my server box, but did not have the issue if I ran the installation from my windows workstation.  What I found during my poking around was that it has something to do with a video driver check on boot--at least, in my case, that is what it was.  To get around it, when the Grub2 menu comes up, select the option to boot in recovery mode.  Once the menu comes up, select the option to continue booting into your Ubuntu install.  Once you have logged in, bring up the terminal and edit the /etc/defaults/grub file and find the line for kernel boot options.  Typically, it will have something like "quiet splash" or something along those lines in the quotes for this option.  Add "nomodeset" to just before the closing quote (without adding the quotes around it) and save the file.  Back at the terminal run "sudo update-grub".  This will apply this on boot.  That was the only way I found to get around it in both GUI and nonGUI setups.  Hope this helps.  If you have any questions, feel free to contact me through my website www.anklebiterwoodworks.com

P.S. Forgot to mention that I did not have this occur on 12.04, but did on 14.04.  Method of correcting is the same, though.

Scott